# Failure in Text read in matlab

Tags: matlab, fopen

```
Reading: 2012-11-14 17:51:30.188000
Orient: 0.128638193011,0.485114246607,0.864937186241,0.347732484341
Gyro: -0.0267551075667,0.0950478315353,-0.131820827723
Accel: -0.199179515243,-0.979403376579,-0.0331153795123
Compass: 0.819754898548,-0.555078268051,-0.141031831503
Reading: 2012-11-14 17:51:30.300000
Orient: 0.102125242352,0.50507569313,0.85701161623,0.353488951921
Gyro: 0.0196692775935,0.134142056108,0.073423832655
Accel: -0.197360157967,-0.978824615479,-0.0543242283165
Compass: 0.823461055756,-0.549835622311,-0.139974221587
```

As above is the data I had which is in `.txt` form... but when I try to read one of the line of the data to display it in `Matlab` I don't manage to display?

Comment: How are you trying to read it? Can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: fid = fopen ('C:\Users\KaeBin\Desktop\log.txt');
[names:,ax,ay,az]= textread (fid, '%s %f %f %f','headerlines',0) 
i tried this way...but got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not give you a solution, but I'll guide you.

```
fid = fopen('C:\Users\KaeBin\Desktop\log.txt');
while ~feof(fid)
   line = fgets(fid);
   title = sscanf(line, ['%s:']);
   if strcmp(title, 'Gyro:')==1
     [name num]=strtok(line, ':');
     num=strtok(num, ':');
     nums_of_gyro=sscanf(num, '%f, %f, %f')
     ....
     ....
   end
   ...
   ...
end
```

**Explanation:**

I'm scanning the text file from the first line until the last:

- `while ~feof(fid)` I read into `line` each line from the file.
- `title = sscanf(line, ['%s:']);` Here I extract the first work in the text file.
- `if strcmp(title, 'Gyro:')==1` Now I check if the first work is `Gyro`. If so, then I extract the relevant information for me (which in this case the three numbers).

Now you can do the same to extract the information from `Accel` and do some manipulation. 
You can easily edit the code, add and remove lines from it in order to achieve your goal.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Maroun...nice meeting you. actually i want to read the 3-axis data from Accel and Gyro to calculate their distance
for example  
Accel: -0.199179515243,-0.979403376579,-0.0331153795123
i want to extract the value in Accel. However, the data receive from sensor is more than the data above. so, how to extract specific data  of it? Thanks...^^

Comment: Matlab will explain it better. Basically it is used to parse a string. Here you go: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html

Comment: Hi, Maroun thanks for the helps..^^ if i wan to continuous read the value of each categories, i need to add counter and condition for it right?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this procedure(just for the first two text lines, but extendable to the whole file):

```
clc, clear all, close all

fid = fopen(filename,'r');

A = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\r');

A = A{1};

a = A{1}(length('Reading')+2:end);
b = A{2}(length('Orient')+2:end);
```

This way you would store the attributes of each text line into a unique array.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ya, i reali appreciate...^^